# Swift Type vs explicitly unwrapped Type

Tags: arrays, swift

I just wanted to use the `.map` closure in Swift and stumbled upon this:

```
//var oldUsers = [User]() -> containting >=1 Users at runtime
//var invitedUsers = [String]() -> gets filled with userIds during runtime by the user clicking on people to invite

let oldIds = self.oldUsers.map {$0.userId} //userId is of Type String!
println(oldIds) //-> returns Array<String!>

var allUsers = self.invitedUsers + oldIds
```

The last line wont compile as it says you cant combine

```
[(String)] and Array<String!>
```

Quick fixed it by just doing a cast in map

```
let oldIds = self.oldUsers.map {$0.userId as String}
```

Shouldnt that be the same? I would understand if I needed to unwrap an optional Array of [String?] first. Why is the cast necessary as the object property is already an explicitly unwrapped type of String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[(String)]` and `Array<String!>` are not at all the same thing.

Also, `String!` is not *explicitly* unwrapped, but rather *implicitly* unwrapped.  It is called implicitly unwrapped because we can try to use it as a `String` without explicitly writing any unwrapping code.  Meanwhile, explicitly writing the unwrap code is referred to as explicitly unwrapping...

But at the end of the day, the point is that `[String]` and `[String!]` are different types.  They seem close enough, but Swift is *very* strict about its types.

What would be the result of combining these two arrays?  Should it be a `[String]`?  Or a `[String!]`?  Either way, it's not the same as the two types that went into it, so it'd would be confusing.  There's not a logical way to determine what sort of an array it should be.

So your options are to either cast the `[String!]` to a `[String]` and hope it holds no `nil` values, or to cast the `[String]` to a `[String!]`, and then you can combine.

Comment: I'd suggest that using `flatMap` instead of `map` would be the best option, avoiding the danger of casting `String!` to `String` and ensuring the array is safe to use there on in. Of course, if a `nil` `userId` is a programming error, then stick with the cast – you want it to crash.

Comment: I'd suggest not using `String!` or `[String!]` at all.  The only reason would be if you're using some terrible Objective-C library that managed to update to typed-arrays but missed the part about the nullability annotations.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't explicitly give the type of your closure, Swift is inferring it for you.

Anyhow, I think casting the result type of your closure is a bit strange, and using the complete closure syntax would be better : 
`let oldIds = self.oldUsers.map {(user) -> String in user.userId}`

Here you explicitly tell Swift that your closure return type is String, so the map result type should be of `[String]`.

Comment: [-1] There is nothing unusual happening with Swift's type inference. `oldIds` is inferred as `[String!]` because `user.userId` is of type `String!`. Also, the suggestion of writing the complete closure syntax is no different from casting using the `as` operator (which just causes the closure to infer the return type as `String`), except that it is a little bit more verbose.

Comment: You're right, I thought userId was of type String. About the closure syntax, I'm not saying it's different, but sometimes verbose is a good thing.